# How to map Swift Error to Objective-C NSError?

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I have some logic implemented in Swift and I need to use it in Objective-C class. And I need to implement Swift protocol in Objective-C. The one method of this Swift protocol contains Error as param. Here is the Swift protocol method, I wan to implement in ObjC:

```
func scheduledLocationManager(_ manager: ScheduledLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
```

How to convert Swift Error to NSError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. Objective-C will automatically see that as

```
- (void)scheduledLocationManager:(ScheduledLocationManager * _Nonnull)manager didFailWithError:(NSError * _Nonnull)error;
```